# Reactor core, take 30 then wait before taking another 30

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Using `reactor.core.publisher.Flux`, how can I take n number of values from a `Flux` and then wait for a duration before taking the next batch?

```
onboardService
  .loadRepositories(user)               // Flux of values
  .take(30)                             // Take 30 from the flux
  .delayElements(Duration.ofMinutes(1)) // Wait one minute
  .doOnEach(...)                        // Process the value
  .???                                  // How to repeat with the next 30?
```

Further in the chain, I'm pushing each value from the `Flux` to a service that has a rate limit of 30 every minute.

```
onboardService
  .loadRepositories(user)   
  .limitRate(10)
  .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
```

Sounds like what I want, however it doesn't behave how I'd expect. Using it with these parameters it waits 10 seconds between processing each individual flux, whereas I'd expect it to process 10, then take another 10.

Is there a better way to not overload the end service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can window the flux and limit each window to one minute:

```java
onboardService.loadRepositories(user)
  .transform(flux ->
               flux
                 .window(30)
                 .zipWith(Flux.interval(Duration.ZERO, Duration.ofMinutes(1)))
                 .flatMap(Tuple2::getT1))
  .doOnEach(...) // Process the value
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of `.window` this is amazing!